# How can you get a binary number with n number of '1's in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I want to generate a random number using uniform(). The maximum value must be equal to the maximum value of a N bit integer.

So I need to generate the value of a binary number with n '1's

Thank you

Comment: The open source OSVVM package includes a uniform based function that can return an array type (representing a binary number) of a specified length in package randompkg. Bigger than 31 bits and it uses two uniform calls.

Comment: (2**N)-1 has N ones in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uniform gives you a real number ranging from 0.0 to 1.0. You need to scale it to fit the desired value range and optionally convert it into a std_logic_vector.

For example for a N bit target value:

```
uniform(seed1, seed2, rand);
rand_int := integer(floor(rand*2.0**N));
sig      <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(rand_int,N));
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't cover the case of N > 31. Uniform has a constrained random range based on the seeds pass as arguments, see the package body for package math real, their type mark is POSITIVE. The solution is make multiple uniform calls and take at most 31 bits out of each one to form values with N > 31 where N specifies the length of `sig`. OSVVM contains such code.  The OP doesn't specify N nor the binary 'integer' type.